# The new lines from en.yml won't get rendered on an html page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, haml

In en.yml I have strings with new lines. When they're rendered on an html page, the new lines disappear -- it's rendered as a single line.

My en.yml:

```
test: |+
  Something fdsafdsfd


  fdsafdsfd
```

Answer (score 1):

YAML returns a string with `\n` for that `test` key. If you want to show it in html you need to convert that new lines to proper html tags. You can use [simple_format](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) helper for that:

```
simple_format("foo\nbar") # => "<p>foo\n<br />bar</p>"
simple_format("foo\n\nbar") # => "<p>foo</p>\n\n<p>bar</p>"
```